# how to take value between sentences in excel

Tags: excel

how to take value between sentences in excel? i have some experiments to separate the values in excel. and I have not found good results using formulas. can you help?

I will take the value and put it in sequence in the range: a1, a2, etc.
so the result i can put a value like this: A1 = 108999000, A2 = 104800000, A3 = 837.51960394, A4 = 90073802063 and etc.

> "data":"best":"108999000","low":"104800000","volume_disk":"837.51960394","vol_thx":"90073802063","last":"108449500","thert":"108359400","konc":"108449500","server_time":1511271745

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you post an image of your spreadsheet? Just FYI, in general, the Excel functions used to find specific text within a cell are `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `MID`, `SEARCH`, and `FIND`.

Comment: Can you sent me example?

Comment: Yes. Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712138/extract-text-from-a-string-in-excel/46712649#46712649).

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 thanks